# How is it possible that a closed null geodesic be incomplete?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, geodesics

In page 190 of "The Large Scale Structure of Spacetime" (Hawking & Ellis), it says:

> ...there must be a closed null geodesic curve $\gamma$ through $q$. Let $v$ be an affine parameter on $\gamma$ (regarded as a map of an open interval of $R^1$ to $M$) and let ... , $v_{-1}$, $v_0$, $v_1$, $v_2$, ... be successive values of $v$ at $q$. Then we may compare at $q$ the tangent vector $\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_0}$ and the tangent Vector $\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_1}$ obtained by parallelly transporting $\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_0}$ round $\gamma$. Since they both point in the same direction, they must be proportional: $\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_1}=a\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_0}$. The factor $a$ has the following significance: the affine distance covered in the $n$th circuit of $\gamma$, $(v_{n+1}-v_n)$, is equal to $a^{-n}(v_1-v_0)$. Thus if $a>1$, $v$ never attains the value $(v_1-v_0)(1-a^{-1})^{-1}$ and so $\gamma$ is geodesically incomplete in the future direction even though one can go round an infinite number of
> times. ...

Now my question is: why shouldn't it be always the case that $a=1$? Since the geodesic $\gamma$ is affine parameterized by $v$, then by definition the tangent vector $\partial/\partial v$ is parallelly transported along $\gamma$, which means $\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_1}=\partial/\partial v|_{v=v_0}$. Then $\gamma$ must be complete($v$ can range from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$) because each time you go round $\gamma$,  $v$ will increase(or decrease) a constant value and you can go infinite times.

It is also intuitively natural to me that a closed null geodesic must be complete: once you finished a "lap" along the closed null geodesic, the spacetime will start to look exactly the same as last "lap" so there's no reason that the affine parameter won't change the same amount as last "lap".

Where did I get it wrong?
If I was wrong, can someone show me a spacetime in which there's a closed null geodesic and it's incomplete?